# Is there a way to send a file to an AWS S3 Bucket while creating it in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I have incominig Data from a Database, which should be written to a CSV-file which again should be stored in a Amazon S3 Bucket. Im not allowed to use very much of my local storage (about 1GB). 
Is it possible to upload the incoming data as a CSV-file without using local storage or with just using that little i have? The file will have more than 10 GB.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to do with AWS SDK, but the crucial thing is **you need to know the file size before starting the upload**

If you know, how big the file will be, then you can prepare your own InputStream and pass it to the S3 client like this:

```
public class DynamicUpload {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create S3 client
        AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3Client.builder().withRegion("eu-central-1").build();
        CsvStream stream = new CsvStream();
        // When providing InputStream, you must set content length
        ObjectMetadata obj = new ObjectMetadata();
        obj.setContentLength(stream.getSize());
        obj.setContentType("text/plain");
        // Pass created InputStream as a source
        s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("files.stirante.com", "stackOverflow.csv", stream, obj));
    }

    private static class CsvStream extends InputStream {

        private static DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("00");
        // Target size for testing purposes
        private int size = 100000;
        // This is size of one row "XX;XX;XX\n"
        private int itemSize = 9;
        // Since we increment it at the very beginning, we set it to -1
        private int currentItemIndex = -1;
        // Current row, we're returning
        private byte[] currentItem = null;
        // Byte index in current row
        private int currentItemByteIndex = 0;

        /**
         * Returns size of the whole file
         */
        public int getSize() {
            return size * itemSize;
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            // Every time read is called, we return another character from created earlier row
            currentItemByteIndex++;
            // If row is not initialized or earlier row was already fully returned, we create another row
            if (currentItem == null || currentItemByteIndex >= itemSize) {
                currentItemIndex++;
                // If we don't have another row, we throw end of file exception
                if (currentItemIndex == size) {
                    throw new EOFException();
                }
                // Format guarantees us, that in case of number smaller than 10, it will still return 2 characters (e.g. 02)
                String s = format.format(Math.random() * 99) + ";" +
                        format.format(Math.random() * 99) + ";" +
                        format.format(Math.random() * 99) + "\n";
                currentItem = s.getBytes();
                currentItemByteIndex = 0;
            }
            return currentItem[currentItemByteIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

[Example generated file](http://files.stirante.com/stackOverflow.csv)

Documentation: [PutObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html)

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways to achieve that:

1. Use multi part file uploading by handling 1 GB per part locally.
   See [example](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html).
2. Use cloud instance instead of local one (where you don't have 1 GB limitation) and use atomic upload (e.g. AmazonS3Client#putObject method)